# Xcode Playground doesn't display on the right side

Tags: ios, xcode, swift-playground

I have this issue while I run my playground. However, it doesn't display on the right side. So, I searched many forums and the only way that worked for me was 
to delete the comments. I use the iOS platform. My Xcode version is 9.4.1 on macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode 9 has some issues in playground and sometimes it stuck at `lunching simulator` or `running playground` or etc. The best solution is update to **Xcode 10+**. Many bugs like this has been resolved in the current version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this as well. I usually have to quit Xcode (cmd + q) or quit from the menu and reopen the playground. That usually runs the simulator.